# streamwriter in windows store app - write text to file in VB

Tags: vb.net, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Does anybody have VB code to emulate Streamwriter for Windows Store?

I know it's been replaced by StorageFolder class but there is no VB sample in MSDN and I can't seem to translate properly from c# examples. Any help would be appreciated. I am just trying to write text (CSV) to a file and save it to the documents folder. In the code below windows store want a stream instead of strPath when I try dim-ing a streamwriter. (been playing with pickerdialog too, but that might be the next hurdle).

```
Dim strpath As String = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary & "\" & strFileName
    'Build String for file*******************
    Dim swExport As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(strpath)

    swExport.Flush()

    For x = 0 To intCount - 1
        strLine = "WriteSomeText"
        swExport.WriteLine(strLine)
    Next x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making it too difficult. To write to a file I just needed to use storagefolder and storagefile. I have also included the FileSavePicker in the code (note that filetypechoices is mandatory)

```
Private Async Function btnExport_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) As Task
    'Calls Filepicker to determine location
    'Calls Sqlite to select ALL
    'Creates CSV file to be saved at location chosen


    'save to file
    Dim intCount As Integer = "5"
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim strLine As String               'hold each line for export file


    'Create FileName based on date
    Dim strDate As String = Date.Today.ToString("MMddyyyy")
    Dim strFileName As String = "Export" & strDate & ".csv"

    ' Configure save file dialog box 
    Dim dlgPicker As New Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker

    'add types for picker (manditory field)
    Dim types = New List(Of String)
    types.Add(".csv")
    types.Add(".txt")

'set picker parameters
    dlgPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Downloads
    dlgPicker.SuggestedFileName = strFileName '"Document"               ' 
    dlgPicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("CSV/TXT", types)             'manditory 
    dlgPicker.DefaultFileExtension = ".csv"                 'Filter files by extension

    dlgPicker.CommitButtonText = "Save"

    ' Show save file dialog box 
    Dim SaveCSV = Await dlgPicker.PickSaveFileAsync()

    '************************get data************
    Dim sbExport As Text.StringBuilder = New Text.StringBuilder
    sbExport.AppendLine(strHeader)
    For x = 0 To intCount - 1
        strLine = "Get the text you want to write here"
        sbExport.AppendLine(strLine)
    Next x
    '************************************
    'write data to file
    Await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(SaveCSV, sbExport.ToString)


    Dim mb As MessageDialog = New MessageDialog("Done")
    Await mb.ShowAsync()


End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the simplest approach would be to use a `MemoryStream` if you like `StreamWriter`, so something like:

```
Dim sessionData As New MemoryStream()
' TODO: stage data in sessionData
Dim swExport As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(sessionData)

swExport.Flush()

For x = 0 To intCount - 1
    strLine = "WriteSomeText"
    swExport.WriteLine(strLine)
Next x

Dim file As StorageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder.CreateFileAsync("towns.json", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)
Using (fileStream As Stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    sessionData.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
    await sessionData.CopyToAsync(fileStream)
    await fileStream.FlushAsync()
End Using
```

Comment: I get an error "fileStream is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level". Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Disregard the comment, I fixed that with a try catch instead of a using. But now I create the file, but it is empty.

Comment: you should be able to see if your memorystream had anything in it?

Comment: I changed my approach to something more simple - I think I was trying to make it more difficult. (I'll post the code)